# Perform code when frame is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame

I have a custom class that's a subclass of `UIView`. In the `storyboard` I set a `UIView's` class to the custom class. The `view` in the `storyboard` has a height `constraint` so that I can change the height programmatically. (I know it's not the only way, but I think it's the easiest way.)

I want to perform some code in the custom class every time the `view's` height changes.

I tried the following:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame  {
    [super setFrame:frame};
    NSLog(@"Frame did change");
}
```

But this method only runs on startup, not when it's (`self`) height was changed. How can I perform code anytime it's frame is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override `layoutSubviews` method in your custom view class

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubviews];
   NSLog(@"Frame did change");
}
```